# focus on last line of a listview binded to a collection - wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, wpf-controls

In a wpf project i've a listview "binded" to a collection
Every time i add an item to the collection i'd like the focus on the listview goes to the last line (to the addeed one)
how to do that?

```
//XAML
<ListView
                x:Name="logListActions"
                Height="200"
                MinHeight="150"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Background="WhiteSmoke"
                BorderThickness="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding LogMessages}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                        <GridViewColumn
                            Width="110"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding When}"
                            Header="Data" />
                        <GridViewColumn
                            Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Message}"
                            Header="Messaggio" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>



//ViewModel
public ObservableCollection<LogMessage> LogMessages
        {
            get { return _logMessageList; }
            set
            {
                _logMessageList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LogMessages");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

After adding new item into Listbox, call below code from code behind:

```
logListActions.ScrollIntoView(item);
logListActions.SelectedItem = item;
```

Comment: where in the code behind? in the xaml.cs file or in the viewmodel? in the view model  the control "logListActions"  is not accessible/Referenceable.
if into of the xaml.cs in which method?

Comment: In the xaml.cs. But you have to identify some event which gets trigger after adding a new item into ListView.

Comment: Another good approach I found here on https://michlg.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/listbox-automatically-scroll-currentitem-into-view/.

Answer (score 1):

Bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView` to a `LogMessage` property in your view model and set the latter to the last added `LogMessage` object:

```
<ListView ... ItemsSource="{Binding LogMessages}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLogMessage}">
```

---

```
private LogMessage _selected;
public LogMessage SelectedLogMessage
{
    get { return _selected; }
    set { _selected = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedLogMessage"); }
}
```

This will *select* the last row. You could then handle the `SelectionChanged` event in the view to focus and highlight it:

```
private void logListActions_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AddedItems != null && e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = logListActions.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.AddedItems[0]) as ListViewItem;
            if (lvi != null)
                lvi.Focus();
        }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
}
```